# SSR- Spartacus : Browser language detection not working because accept-language header is empty

Tags: server-side-rendering, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We implement the browser language detection en SSR based on accept-language header retrieved from the Request Object.

the logic works fine on Staging environnement + locally with SSR, but on production after adding some logs , the header (accept-language) is empty in SSR.

**Implementation : **

```
    private getBrowserLanguage(): string | null {
        let language;
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            language = this.winRef.nativeWindow?.navigator.language;
        }
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            language = this.request.headers['accept-language'] || '';
        }
        if (language) {
            language = language.slice(0, 2);
            return language;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there any reason why this header is missing only on production ?
Is there another approch to get the browser language on SSR ?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What kind of request are you checking? At first look it doesn't look like Spartacus issue.

Comment: Ideas from top of my head... Maybe in Production environment this header is not forwarded further by the reverse proxy server? Would you mind checking the logs in your production reverse proxy and check what headers are present in the requests? Also ,for debugging purposes, could you dump all headers that are present in `this.request` in the app? Btw. if you're using `REQUEST` token from `@nguniversal/express-engine`, AFAIK the ExpressJS Request object doesn't have a field `.headers`, but only a method `.get()` which returns headers. For more see docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get